# Evaluating $\sum_{i=0}^{m-1} [ \frac{b + ia}m ]$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Let $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $m\in\mathbb{Z}_{>1}$
Evaluate

$[\frac {b}{m}] + [\frac {(b+a)}{m}]+ [\frac {(b+2a)}{m}]+ [\frac {(b+3a)}{m}]+ [\frac {(b+4a)}{m}]+ [\frac {(b+5a)}{m}]+.....+ [\frac {(b+(m-1)a)}{m}]
$

Attempt at this solution: I tried to use *Hermite Identity.*

Assuming that $x = \frac {b}{m} $ and $\frac {1}{n} = \frac {a}{m}$, I got

$[x] + [x + \frac {1}{n}] + [x + \frac {2}{n}] +\dots+ [x + \frac {(n-1)}{n}] = [nx]
$

However, $\frac {a}{m}$ is not an integer so I can't use it. I'm stuck what to do?

Comment: Maybe look up a proof of the Hermite identity, and see how you can tweak it to handle your sum.

Comment: Another idea; do a ton of numerical examples, look for a pattern, then try to prove the pattern holds up.

Comment: I need a formal proof..

Comment: Proof of what? At this point, you have nothing to prove, you haven't even made a guess as to what the answer might be. When you have an idea of what the answer might be, then you can start to look for a proof.

Answer (score 1):

[Hermite's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite%27s_identity) was generalized for example in Graham, Knuth and Patashnik's famous 'Concrete Mathematics' where they obtained (page $90$ to $94$ so that I won't reproduce it here... pdf files for this book are easier to find than google print previews ;-) so no direct link : everybody should own The Original !) the equation $(3.32)$ : 
$$\boxed{\displaystyle\sum_{0\le k<m}\left\lfloor\frac{b+ka}m \right\rfloor=d\left\lfloor\frac bd\right\rfloor+\frac{(m-1)(a-1)}2+\frac{d-1}2\quad\text{with}\ \ d=\gcd(m,a)}$$
with $\ m,\ a\ $ positive integers and $\,b\,$ any real.

This allowed them to obtain the nice 'reciprocity law' :
$$\sum_{0\le k<m}\left\lfloor\frac{b+k\,a}m \right\rfloor=\sum_{0\le k<a}\left\lfloor\frac{b+k\,m}a \right\rfloor$$

Comment: what is the final answer?

Comment: @rattanjot: I specified the ranges for the variables used and the answer.

Comment: if d = gcd(m,n) then we
get the numbers 0, d, 2d, . . . , m - d in some order, followed by d - 1 more
copies of the same sequence.   Can u prove this.. plz..?

Comment: @rattanjot: Sorry but I don't understand what you want me to prove here. Do you change a parameter to get these results ? If yes which one ? If this is an allusion to CM which exact part? ...

Comment: page no 93 last paragraph that says ...................................    In these two cases we have gcd( 12,5) = 1 and gcd( 12,8) = 4. The general
rule, which we will prove next chapter, states that if d = gcd(m,n) then we
get the numbers 0, d, 2d, . . . , m - d in some order, followed by d - 1 more
copies of the same sequence. For example, with m = 12 and n = 8 the pattern
0, 8, 4 occurs four times.
The first column of

Comment: @rattanjot: This part is proved later at the start of $4.8$ (page $129,\ 130$ with $m\perp n$ meaning that $\gcd(m,n)=1$). Sorry for the delay...